# Selenium Webdriver : Scroll to the top using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nodes

i'm using Selenium webdriver with javascript & node.js

In some step in my test, i have to automate clicking to a buuton which is in the top of the page.

But as i'm doing some previous treatment ,  *the page automatically scrolls to the bootom* , and as a result my button (on the top) is no longer appearing , so i'm catching this error:

```
Uncaught WebDriverError: unknown error: Element <li>...</li> is not clickable at point (707, 10). Other element would receive the click: <li class="menumain crm-Campaigns" tabindex="11">...</li>
```

with some googling i fin that i should **scroll to the top** to make appearing the button .

**How i may do it ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it this way :

```
driver.executeScript('scroll(0, -250);').then(function() {
    driver.sleep(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code you will be able to scroll up :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)", "");
OR,
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Comment: He is using Selenium webdriver with javascript & node.js. Your example is for java binding?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

This will scroll to the top left corner of your page. But in most cases, this will be equivalent to the top.

Comment: i'm running under node.js , it s not a simple graphic scrolling   -> Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to the top of the page,get hold of the xpath or id of the button.
The code here shows for clicking the button using selenium.
`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('button').click();");`

For scrolling use the code below
`jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-200)", "");`

Comment: He is using Selenium webdriver with javascript & node.js. Your example is for java binding?